# Jquery find all divs with id="" and change their text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs, some have ids and some don't. I want to find all the divs inside a class which ids match `id=""` and change the inner text to `"no data available"`. Is this possible?

I tried using `$("*[id]")` but it didn't work. This is how my list looks.

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `[id]` matches all elements that have an `id` attribute. If you want to specify that they have an empty value, you need to use `[id='']`.

Comment: An id attribute, if present, must have a value with at least one character. Those empty ones are invalid markup. Just leave the id off entirely.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should avoid duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently some browsers (e.g. Chrome) will take your empty ID and change it from `id=""` to just `id`. One way to then handle this is to loop through them and check for an empty value:

```js
$("div[id]").each(function(){
    if(this.id==='')$(this).html('no data available')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="4">4</div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="7">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS to target the elements with no value in the attribute. No JavaScript is needed.

```css
div [id] {
   background-color: green;
   width: 200px;
   height: 1.5em;
   margin: .5em;
}

div [id=""] {
   background-color: red;
}

div [id=""]::after {
  content: "no data available"
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="7"></div>
</div>
```

If you really want to do it with JavaScript/jQuery, you can just select the elements and filter out the ones with an id.

```js
$('div[id]').filter((i,e)=>!e.id.length).text('no data available')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id=""></div>
  <div id="7"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter empty id's.

```
$(".main div").filter(function() {
      return !$(this).attr("id");      
});
```